# Converting ill-formed csv file to numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a csv file with 7 rows, out of which 5 rows have 7 columns and the last two have 2 columns. These files are also a mix of strings, floats and NaNs. 
e.g:

```
883825.00,373395.00,0.00,"20,080.84",2012500.00,#EANF#,121449.39
0.00,0.00,0.00,"38,849.10",0.00,#EANF#,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,"83,167.42",1640625.00,#EANF#,0.00
#EANF#,#EANF#,#EANF#,#EANF#,#EANF#,#EANF#,#EANF#
"-1,202,600.00",-0.00,#EANF#,2267168,0.00,#EANF#,"-173,710.66"
-125.60,#EANF#
"17,459.68",#EANF#.
```

I could read this file using MATLAB and work on it. Can I do the same with numpy?
I tried looking for the solution on this forum but nothing seems to work. Need to convert the strings and NaNs to float.

Comment: What is the expected result for the last two rows?

Comment: The expected result is just -125.6 and 17459.68 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a solution using NumPy, `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` raise errors and warnings respectively if the number of columns change, so you'll probably have to write your own method.

***Edit**: The following was edited slightly to refelct DSM's comment.*

You could use the built-in `csv` module:

```
import csv

arr = []

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            arr.extend(row)
```

The csv approach has the advantage that it strips newlines, which is not the case if you just read the file using `fileobj = open(...)` and `for line in fileobj`.

At this point you should have

```
>>> arr
['883825.00', '373395.00', '0.00', '20,080.84', '2012500.00', '#EANF#', '121449.
39', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '38,849.10', '0.00', '#EANF#', '0.00', '0.00', '0.0
0', '0.00', '83,167.42', '1640625.00', '#EANF#', '0.00', '#EANF#', '#EANF#', '#E
ANF#', '#EANF#', '#EANF#', '#EANF#', '#EANF#', '-1,202,600.00', '-0.00', '#EANF#
', '2267168', '0.00', '#EANF#', '-173,710.66', '-125.60', '#EANF#', '17,459.68',
 '#EANF#.']
```

You then have to convert to floats and replace the `#EANF#` values with, say, `numpy.NaN`. We also have to take care of the commas in some of the values. The commas are easily handled with

```
float(str(float_string).replace(',', ''))
```

For the `#EANF#` values we can just check if an item starts with this (not equal to this, since the last item in the list has a trailing `.`). Combining these two conversions into a function `convert` and wrapping with a list comprehension we have:

```
import numpy

def convert(v):
    try:
        return float(v)
    except ValueError:
        if v.startswith('#EANF#'):
            return numpy.NaN
        else:
            return float(str(v).replace(',', ''))

arr = numpy.asarray([convert(a) for a in arr])
```

The function `convert` could be generalised to take a second, optional argument which defines which values should be mapped to `numpy.NaN`.

The final result of this is

```
>>> arr
[883825.0, 373395.0, 0.0, 20080.84, 2012500.0, nan, 121449.39, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 38
849.1, 0.0, nan, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 83167.42, 1640625.0, nan, 0.0, nan, nan, na
n, nan, nan, nan, nan, -1202600.0, -0.0, nan, 2267168.0, 0.0, nan, -173710.66, -
125.6, nan, 17459.68, nan]
```

Note: this answer assumes that you are happy with a one dimensional list as the result. If you want a different shape for the result you should say so in the question.

Comment: "(it treats this as a signle value - does anyone know a way around this?)" I think it *is* a single value, simply with commas as the thousands separator.  That's why those values are quoted.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that - the csv module is therefore definately the way forward. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! I gave up on doing this with Python because it worked out with Excel itself. Will try it out sometime when I have learnt more of Python. Thanks and sorry for the delay in answering.